# Accessing an Immediately Invoked Function Expression variable in Node.js in another file using require

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-modules

File 1 - Monitor.js

```
var MONITOR = (function () {

// File Content

return {
  doThing: function() {
    doThing();
  }
};
})();
```

File 2 - Test.js

`var monitor = require('../public/js/monitor.js');`

I want to access `doThing()` in File 2. I have tried various syntax and no luck so far.

From the frontend HTML I can simply include Monitor.js in a script tag, and call `MONITOR.doThing();` without trouble but in Test.js this is proving difficult.

Any advice on how?

Comment: You have to export `MONITOR` so that someone else can access it with `require()`.  Add `module.exports = MONITOR` at the bottom of Monitor.js.

Comment: @jfriend00 - This almost works, I can now access "monitor" in file 2, and when I print monitor in file 2 it returns my methods.

But when I actually invoke those methods, the result is always undefined, the functions seem to lack definition.


`var monitor = require('../public/js/monitor.js');`
`var x = monitor.doThing()`
`console.log(x) // returns undefined always`

Any ideas?

Comment: You `doThing()` method has no return value so it will always retrurn `undefined`.  You have to `return someValue` in that method if you want it to have a return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to export MONITOR so that someone else can access it with `require()`.

Add this:

```
module.exports = MONITOR;
```

at the bottom of Monitor.js.

---

And, if you want the `monitor.doThing()` method to return some value, then you have to add a `return` statement to the function as in:

```
var MONITOR = (function () {

// File Content

return {
  doThing: function() {
    return "hello";
  }
};
})();
```